# $_SESSION variables in msqli_query

Tags: php, variables, session

I'm trying to use a session variable in a mqsli_query statment but it doesn't work

```
$result = mysqli_query($link, 'SELECT book_ID, Title, username as author from users,books
here users.user_ID = books.user_ID and username = "{$_SESSION['sess_username']}"' );
```

I tried using real values for username = "" and it works so it means that the query is fine. It doesnt work when I try to use session variable

sample code that works when username is set to real value:

```
$result = mysqli_query($link, 'SELECT book_ID, Title, username as author from users,books
here users.user_ID = books.user_ID and username = "kllew"' );
```

Comment: The syntax highlighter shows your problem

Comment: sorry but I don't understand. That part when 'sess_username' is black?  I'm really new to this.

Comment: Try using [prepared statements](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "correct" method here is prepared statements.  Never again will you need to concat strings into an SQL query or worry about quotes.

```
$query = $link->prepare('SELECT book_ID, Title, username as author from users,books
    where users.user_ID = books.user_ID and username = ?');
$books = array();

if($query){
    // Bind the value to the `?`
    $query->bind_param('s', $_SESSION['sess_username']);
    $query->execute();
    // These variables will be created and populated with your values
    $query->bind_result($book_ID, $title, $author);
    while($query->fetch()){
        // Each time `fetch()` is, called, the variables will be
        // automagically updated with the next row's value
        // This while loop will run for each row, then stop
        $books[] = array(
            'book_ID' => $book_ID,
            'title' => $title,
            'author' => $author
        );
    }
}
else{
    die($link->error);
}

var_dump($books);
```

DOCS: http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php

EDIT: If you have the [`mysqlnd`](https://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqlnd.php) driver installed (usually called `php-mysqlnd`), then you can do this:

```
$query = $link->prepare('SELECT book_ID, Title, username as author from users,books
    where users.user_ID = books.user_ID and username = ?');
$books = array();

if($query){
    // Bind the value to the `?`
    $query->bind_param('s', $_SESSION['sess_username']);
    $query->execute();

    // This allows you to use `fetch_array` like if you had used `mysqli_query`
    $result = $query->get_result();
    $books = $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
}
else{
    die($link->error);
}

var_dump($books);
```

Comment: so do i continue with $result = msqli_query($link, $query) ? ...

Comment: @user3632739: No.  `$query->execute()` runs your query.  Your results will be stored in `$book_ID`, `$title`, and  `$author` when `$query->fetch()` is called.  Prepared statements are a little different.

Comment: so can i store $book_ID, $title and $author in  an array? how?  
 i need to store them in an array cuz i have code that fetches them as an array and displays them. 
<?php foreach ($books as $book): ?>

<li class="active"><a href=""><span class="pull-right">May 1st</span><i class="icon-fire"></i> <?php echo htmlspecialchars($book['Title'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?> <strong> - </strong><em><?php echo htmlspecialchars($book['author'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');?></em></a></li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>

Comment: How many rows does your query return?  If it's only one, then you can do: `$result = array();  $query->bind_result($result['book_ID'], $result['title'], $result['author']); $query->fetch()`.

Comment: @user3632739: You can just simply add them to an array in the `while` loop.

Comment: how can I add points to your reputation? hehe

Comment: Click the up arrow to upvote this post, maybe.

Comment: can't.. says i need 15 reputation. 

anyway, thanks again. you made my made. hope you have a good day as well. ciao

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead: (put the session in var, and change how you are using single quotes.

```
$session = $_SESSION['sess_username'];
$result = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT book_ID, Title, username as author from users,books
here users.user_ID = books.user_ID and username = '$session'" );
```

Comment: been trying that too. doesn't work. thanks for your answer anyway

Comment: you're session variable is set to something right?

Comment: @alex: You forgot your quotes around the value in the SQL query.  P.S. you can just do this: `"SELECT ... AND username = '{$_SESSION['sess_username']}'"`.

Comment: oh oops didn't even notice that, thanks

Comment: @alex im sorry but im really new to this, what do you mean by putting the session in var? ..like this? $_SESSION[$var] ?

Comment: no, i meant store it in the variable $session (var being short for variable).